# How to map a function on a list and append the new values onto the same list multiple times?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following array:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])
```

I am trying to get a list appended on this list, but the new list has added each element by 10. I need this to complete 30 times.

For example, the output should be

```
array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 12, 12, 15, 15, 13, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 22, 22, 25, 25, 23, ...])
```

I have the following code so far. I don't know how to iterate it for 30 times.

```
np.append(np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3]),np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])+10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcasted addition does the trick:

```
In [42]: arr+np.arange(0,4)[:,None]*10
Out[42]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  4,  4,  6,  6,  6,  2,  2,  5,  5,  3],
       [11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 12, 12, 15, 15, 13],
       [21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 22, 22, 25, 25, 23],
       [31, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 32, 32, 35, 35, 33]])
```

and since you want a 1d version:

```
In [43]: (arr+np.arange(0,4)[:,None]*10).ravel()
Out[43]: 
array([ 1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  4,  4,  6,  6,  6,  2,  2,  5,  5,  3, 11, 11,
       11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 12, 12, 15, 15, 13, 21, 21, 21, 23,
       23, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 22, 22, 25, 25, 23, 31, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34,
       34, 36, 36, 36, 32, 32, 35, 35, 33])
```

What we are adding to each `row`:

```
In [44]: np.arange(0,4)[:,None]*10
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop that runs 30 times.

```
template = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])
arr = np.array([])
for i in range(30):
    arr = np.append(arr, template + i * 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np 
x=np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])
print(np.concatenate([x,x+10,x+20]))
```

Better way with 30 repititions:

```
import numpy as np
template = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])
print((template+np.arange(0,4)[:,None]*10).flatten())
```

Comment: This doesn't have 30 repetitions.

Comment: If he could make a for loop himself he wouldn't have posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
new_a = np.concatenate([a+(i*10) for i in range(0,31)])
```

where `a` is your original array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to concatenate the arrays not append them to get a list of arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3])

result = np.concatenate([a + 10*i for i in range(30)])
```

Note that the list comprehension starts at i = 0, representing your original array and ends at i = 29, adding 290 to each element of your original array.

If you do want a list of arrays, the list comprehension, `[a + 10*i for i in range(30)]` will provide that.